# flexbox + bootstrap causing column to go to next line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am new to trying out flexbox.  I am combining it with bootstrap to have a general fluid grid as well.  The issue is that whenever I put flexwrap on the row the columns move to the next line even though the % equals out to 100% or close to depending on which grid you use.  The html:

```
<section class="row">
  <article class="block col-lg-6 img btm-right-title">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Hello</h1><img src="assets/images/prod-grid-sq-mbrace.jpg" alt="Verizon Vehicle delivers next generation pinpoint roadside assistance, mechanics hotline, vehicle diagnostics">
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="block col-lg-6 img btm-left-title">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Goodbye</h1><img src="assets/images/prod-grid-wide-vv.jpg" alt="Verizon Vehicle delivers next generation pinpoint roadside assistance, mechanics hotline, vehicle diagnostics">
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="block col-lg-4 title top-right-title">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Title Block 1</h1>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="block col-lg-4 title top-left-title position-1">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Title Block 2</h1>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="block col-lg-4 title center-title">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Title Block 3</h1>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

I purposely am leaving these in one row as the POC needs to have each block rearranged depending on screen size so I was going to use flexbox to achieve this.

The CSS:

```
*, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: .9em;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    order: 1;
}

.block .content {
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 100%;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    min-height: 300px;
}

.block .content h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

.block.title .content {
    background: red;
}

.block.btm-right-title .content {
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.block.btm-left-title .content {
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.block.top-left-title .content {
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.block.top-right-title .content {
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.block.center-title .content {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.block.img h1 {
    color: #fff;
}

.block.title h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-style: italic;
}

.img img {  
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

.block.img .content {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

I am using jquery to take the images within the content blocks to set them as a background image to allow for background-size cover, but still maintaining the SEO aspects that images provide.  This is currently just a POC and I am just testing so it might be a little sloppy.

The two col-lg-6 should be side by side and the 3 col-lg-4's should also be side by side, instead I am getting this:

[image]

Comment: *Generally* `flexbox` and Bootstrap don't work well together. The latter uses floats which don't work well in conjunction with flexbox. Plus `flexbox` is about *flexible* boxes but Bootstrap uses fixed % widths on it's classes. As you can see, you have quite fight of ethos here. You might want to think again.

Comment: Would I not need to have widths defined if I want to get particular grid sizes?  Do you have any other recommendations that provide the benfits of element positioning that flexbox provides while still using the requested bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the cause.  Bootstrap has certain items marked as display table which is causing conflicts with flexbox.  I am wrapping everything with a row class.  Bootstrap has this css:

```
.btn-group-vertical>.btn-group:after, .btn-group-vertical>.btn-group:before, .btn-toolbar:after, .btn-toolbar:before, .clearfix:after, .clearfix:before, .container-fluid:after, .container-fluid:before, .container:after, .container:before, .dl-horizontal dd:after, .dl-horizontal dd:before, .form-horizontal .form-group:after, .form-horizontal .form-group:before, .modal-footer:after, .modal-footer:before, .nav:after, .nav:before, .navbar-collapse:after, .navbar-collapse:before, .navbar-header:after, .navbar-header:before, .navbar:after, .navbar:before, .pager:after, .pager:before,   .panel-body:after, .panel-body:before, .row:after, .row:before {
 display: table;
 content: '';
}
```

Making this display: initial reset it and caused everything to work as intended.